# How can I include a path outside the Wamp www folder using php.ini ?

Tags: php, include, wamp

My projects uses some global files that should be included outside the www folder.

I have tried to include the path in the php.ini like this

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\Users\Pim\Documents\CMS\globals\php"
```

this global php folder contains some files I want to include in my project within the www folder.

for example, I want to include c:\Users\Pim\Documents\CMS\globals\php\system\init.php
by doing this in de index.php within the www-folder:

```
include 'system/init.php';
```

What am i doing wrong so far?

When i check the phpinfo of my localhost, I says:

> include_path
>   .;c:\php\includes;c:\Users\Pim\Documents\CMS\globals\php; (Local
>   Value) .;c:\php\includes;c:\Users\Pim\Documents\CMS\globals\php;
>   (Master Value)

Comment: "What am i doing wrong so far?" Are you getting errors? Did it blow up your pc? Did it set your cat on fire?

Comment: I'm getting an error when i run my localhost saying 
Warning: include(system/init.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Using `include 'system/init.php';` tells PHP to include from a specific folder.

You are telling php the folder should exist below the current folder the script is execution from.

Try

```
include 'init.php';
```

Then it will search the include path

Comment: The thing is, I want to run an existing project on my wamp server without changing the php code of that project. So if there is a reference to 'system/init.php' i would like to keep it that way so don't need to check all system includes in the entire project and change them to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to include using relative path?

I'm using xampp `include "/tmp/test.php"` at `C:/tmp/test.php` from xampp htdocs and it has worked.

You're doing it as `include "tmp/test.php"` which is including the child directory